# transfer String and file through socket

Tags: java, file, sockets, stream

i would like to transfer file from server to client. before that i want to send file names from specific directory. the file is not transferring as the read is returning -1. can any one correct me where i am going wrong?

My client code goes like this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class PC1Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
    byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
    int bytesRead;
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",3000);
    InputStream is1 = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));
    String st = br.readLine();

    System.out.println(st);
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    fos = new FileOutputStream("F:\\ANI1.TXT");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
    System.out.println(bytesRead);
     do {
         System.out.println("s");
         baos.write(aByte);
         bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
        } while (bytesRead != -1);
    bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
}
}
```

My server code goes like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class PC1Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            String str="";
            Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
            File file = new File("D:\\ani");
            for(File fi : file.listFiles() )
            {
                str=str+fi.getName()+";";
            }
            PrintWriter outname = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            outname.println(str);
            outname.flush();
            outname.close();
            System.out.println("hello der");
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream() );
            File myfile  = new File("d:/hello.txt");
            byte[] mybyte = new byte[(int)myfile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myfile));
            bis.read(mybyte, 0, mybyte.length);
            out.write(mybyte, 0, mybyte.length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few notes: 
`byte[] aByte = new byte[1];` is pointless - it forces you to read the file 1 byte at a time.
`InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();` what is the point of opening the same input stream second time?

`outname.close();` in your server code is what causes your problem.
Why do you close your output stream just to reopen it again?